# Signal/Method for every executed sql statement

Tags: django

According to this 12 years old issue, django does not support a signal for every executed sql statement: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5415

I need this in a production environment where debug=False.

This means overwriting connection.queries does not work.

Is there a way to run some custom code after each sql statement (even if debug=False)?

Comment: Is it possible to write an own database engine subclassing (for example 'django.db.backends.postgresql')? Related: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

Answer (score 11):

I've taken a look at how Django populates `connection.queries`. When `DEBUG = True`, the base database backend code that is used by all backend wraps the database-specific cursors with [`CursorDebugWrapper`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2007e11d7069b0f6ed673c7520ee7f480f07de68/django/db/backends/utils.py#L94). Otherwise, it uses [`CursorWrapper`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2007e11d7069b0f6ed673c7520ee7f480f07de68/django/db/backends/utils.py#L16). It would be in theory possible to force Django to populate it even when `DEBUG = False` by overriding the [`queries_logged`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2007e11d7069b0f6ed673c7520ee7f480f07de68/django/db/backends/base/base.py#L148) property or setting the flag `force_debug_cursor` on the database connection object. Either method would force Django to use `CursorDebugWrapper` even when `DEBUG` is `False`. However, I don't recommend this approach because `CursorDebugWrapper` is not particularly efficient for cases where the only thing you want is to know that a query was executed. For instance, besides populating `connection.queries` it logs the queries to a logger. If you do not need this logging, then it is just a waste.

So taking inspiration from how `CursorDebugWrapper` works, I've come up with a custom way to know when a SQL query has been made.

I created an app called `first` whose `__init__.py` is:

```
from django.db.backends import utils
from contextlib import contextmanager

# This is inspired by Django's stock CursorDebugWrapper class.
class Mixin(object):

    def execute(self, sql, params=None):
        with self.notify(sql, params, use_last_executed_query=True):
            return super().execute(sql, params)

    def executemany(self, sql, param_list):
        with self.notify(sql, param_list):
            return super().executemany(sql, param_list)

    @contextmanager
    def notify(self, sql=None, params=None, use_last_executed_query=False):
        try:
            yield
        finally:
            if use_last_executed_query:
                sql = self.db.ops.last_executed_query(self.cursor, sql, params)
            # I've used print for this proof-of-concept, replace with whatever
            # mechanism suits you.
            print("Executed: ", sql)

class CustomWrapper(Mixin, utils.CursorWrapper):
    pass

class CustomDebugWrapper(Mixin, utils.CursorDebugWrapper):
    pass

utils.CursorWrapper = CustomWrapper
utils.CursorDebugWrapper = CustomDebugWrapper
```

Then in my `settings.py` file, I've put the `first` app first `INSTALLED_APPS`. This makes it so that the `__init__.py` file for it executes before anything that accesses the database.

What this is doing is essentially replacing the stock `CursorWrapper` and `CursorDebugWrapper` classes with custom ones that allow knowing when an SQL query has occurred. This change takes effect for all the backends that are shipped with Django.

I don't know of another way to add this capability in one fell swoop like I'm doing above. I first looked to see if I could derive a new backend from an existing one. I'm sure it is doable but it requires *a lot* of boilerplate. Also, projects that use multiple backends at once would have to derive a new backend for each stock backend that was originally used.

Answer (score 3):

I do believe that the interesting solution posted by @Louis should be flagged as the the correct one.

Having said this, if your need is that of logging and analyzing all executed queries, you might consider installing django-debug-toolbar and configuring it to be optionally available in production for the superuser or a specific administration user.

For example, put this in `myproject/settings.py`:

```
def show_toolbar(request):
    from constance import config
    if not config.DEBUG_SHOW_TOOLBAR:
        return False
    return request.user.is_superuser


DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
    'SHOW_TOOLBAR_CALLBACK': 'myproject.settings.show_toolbar',
    'INTERCEPT_REDIRECTS': False,
}
```

django-debug-toolbar has a specific panel with very detailed informations about all database activity.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could add a [logger to your db backends](https://www.dabapps.com/blog/logging-sql-queries-django-13/):

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('django.db.backends')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) #set the log level you want
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
```

This will track all database transactions.

I remember seeing this some years ago, but I think it should work, since the logging system is pretty much the same.

It is not a signal, but I think it would do what you want.

Comment: That's what I did in the first place, but unfortunately it doesn't work with DEBUG=False: "For performance reasons, SQL logging is only enabled when settings.DEBUG is set to True, regardless of the logging level or handlers that are installed.". See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/logging/#django-db-backends